# Best way to retrieve and filter a directus collection inside a custom endpoint?

Tags: directus

I would need to search an item inside a collection and then work on that item.

What is the correct way to query a collection inside a custom endpoint?
Should i use the API or do you provide any classes?

I tried to follow the current guide https://github.com/directus/docs/blob/master/api/data.md
but i get a 403 (Forbidden) error.

Comment: Can you please share your code, so others can easily help you? :-)

Comment: Data Access Documentation: https://docs.directus.io/advanced/api/data.html for reference, since your URL just expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came around the same problem and now working with directus for some time. I asked the same question at [the discussion section](https://github.com/directus/directus/discussions/14656) but the [example in the guidebook](https://docs.directus.io/extensions/endpoints.html#example-recipes) should help:

```
export default (router, { services, exceptions }) => {
    const { ItemsService } = services;
    const { ServiceUnavailableException } = exceptions;

    router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
        const recipeService = new ItemsService('recipes', { schema: req.schema, accountability: req.accountability });

        recipeService
            .readByQuery({ sort: ['name'], fields: ['*'] })
            .then((results) => res.json(results))
            .catch((error) => {
                return next(new ServiceUnavailableException(error.message));
            });
    });
};
```

Maybe it is a bit late but hopefully it inspires others. Directus is from my first experiences now really great and worth to try.